# Control flow graph from executable?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, executable

Is there a tool available to do so, for x86 programs that is. What I want is for that tool to take the binary executable as an input and show me a control flow graph.

Comment: Found this, http://bap.ece.cmu.edu/

Comment: I doubt you would be able to read something from such a graph of more than a simple sample program. The control flow is just to complex. Besides that any indirect calls (i.e using a vtable) cannot be statically graphed.

Comment: @PMF: You can assume its a simplified program with no indirect calls and such.

Comment: I don't know of such a program.

Comment: Some sort of debugger, presumably.  If th eprogram is any larger, or mor ecomplex, than 'Hello world', it's gonna be really slow and the output really long.  With processes with built-in indeterminacy, eg multithreaded apps, analysing the output across multiple cores would be imp.. 'really, really challenging'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/) can produce nice control-flow graphs, both for individual functions and the whole program.

You can try out [freeware](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml) or [demo](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_demo.shtml) version.

Disclaimer: I work for Hex-Rays.

Comment: could you answer my question here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619663/ida-pro-gragh-output-batch-mode`, I would like to find a way to output cfg in batch mode. thanks